# Why are cgroups mapped differently on these two systems by systemd

Tags: linux-kernel, systemd, cgroups

I have two systems, both running customized variants of OpenSuSE 12.2 (Mantis), both running exactly the same kernel. I get two very different outputs of `/proc/self/cgroup` or `/proc/$$/cgroup` on the two systems:

System A (or a stock OpenSuSE 12.1):

```
cat /proc/self/cgroup 
9:perf_event:/
8:blkio:/
7:net_cls:/
6:freezer:/
5:devices:/
4:memory:/
3:cpuacct,cpu:/
2:cpuset:/
1:name=systemd:/user/root/6
```

System B:

```
root@msx:/sys/fs/cgroup> cat /proc/self/cgroup 
9:perf_event:/
8:blkio:/
7:net_cls:/
6:freezer:/
5:devices:/
4:memory:/
3:cpuacct,cpu:/system/serial-getty@.service/ttyS0
2:cpuset:/
1:name=systemd:/system/serial-getty@.service/ttyS0
```

Why are lines 1 different and why is line 3 present in one and absent in the other? I can find no configuration differences between the two systems.  They run the same version of systemd (`systemd-44-10.1.1.x86_64`).  If I duplicate the sysctl values it has no effect.  The boot options are the same.  I've compared everything in `/etc`, `/usr`, and `/lib` to see if there are any relevant configuration differences.  (There are different installed RPMs but none that lay down any system configuration files, and I think I removed all the custom RPMs.)

This is more than a curiosity factor because on System B, we cannot create a `SCHED_RR` thread, but on System A, we can.  If I set `DefaultController` to `NULL` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, it works, and line 3 disappears (lines 1 remain different).  It also works if I write the process ID of the invoking shell into `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct`:

```
root@msx:/root> ./a.out
Creation of real-time thread FAILED - Operation not permitted
root@msx:/root> cat /proc/$$/cgroup
9:perf_event:/
8:blkio:/
7:net_cls:/
6:freezer:/
5:devices:/
4:memory:/
3:cpuacct,cpu:/system/sshd.service
2:cpuset:/
1:name=systemd:/system/sshd.service
root@msx:/root> echo $$ > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/tasks
root@msx:/root> ./a.out
root@msx:/root> cat /proc/$$/cgroup
9:perf_event:/
8:blkio:/
7:net_cls:/
6:freezer:/
5:devices:/
4:memory:/
3:cpuacct,cpu:/
2:cpuset:/
1:name=systemd:/system/sshd.service
```

Not sure why this works.  My colleagues aren't satisfied that the problem is understood, as it shouldn't require this configuration change.

Kernel is 3.4.47, `CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED` is enabled, `CONFIG_AUTOGROUP` is enabled (disabling still doesn't work but it does fail differently)

This is a spinoff of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412336/how-to-check-for-permissions-for-sched-setscheduler.

Comment: How do you log in?

Comment: @Hauke -- Logging in works fine; normally I log in via serial console as in this example, but ssh works as well (and has the same behavior).

Comment: @Hauke -- ok I see an anomaly in the last example; I must have inadvertently cut and pasted from two different runs.  I just did one run and rewrote the example so the login method is consistent before and after the test!

Comment: What's the output of `mount | grep cgroup` on each system?

Comment: cat /proc/cgroups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a system.conf configuration option, DefaultControllers, that controls which cgroup hierarchies are attached to. By default it's cpu.  I set it to null and /proc/$$$/cgroup no longer lists the getty process under cpuacct,cpu, and the test program works. Why the same configuration file -- I was using the default which is in use on both systems -- produced two different results, I don't know. I'm not sure this is the best way to solve the problem or why it works.  So I changed

```
#DefaultControllers=cpu
```

to

```
DefaultControllers=
```

in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and it works.